# Change attribute group through SQL

Tags: magento2, attribute-group

Due to a migration, some products have a wrong (not existing) attribute group.

Is there a simple way to change this with a SQL query?

If yes, where can I see wich attribute-group is wich...

Comment: This is the 'error' i get in the reports:

a:4:{i:0;s:48:"No such entity with attributeSetId = 31";i:1;s:9778:"#0 /home/...../domains/......./public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/GroupRepository.php(116): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('attributeSetId', '31')
......

Answer (score 0):

You can create setup script in custom module or run provided code in custom controller

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Setup;
```

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

```
/**
 * Installs data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

    $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->load();
    foreach ($collection as $product){
         $product->getId();
         $productData = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
    $attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
    $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->set(/*your attribute set id*/); 
    //OR 
    $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName("attributeSetName");
    $productData->save();
    } 

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but how do i actually do that? 
I't for Magento 2 btw

Comment: its for magento2 , you can use this script in any module or custom module or else you can create custom controller and execute it with code , just remove startsetup and endsetup from code